# jQuery Countdown Timer Multiple Instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

When using [The Final Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) jQuery timer, it's easy to make a timezone aware timer based on one of the examples they provide. But now I want to use multiple instances on one page and don't know how. The code they provide for using multiple instances is this:

HTML:

```
<div data-countdown="2016/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2017/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2018/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2019/01/01"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
  $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
    $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
  });
});
```

Doesn't look to difficult but when trying to implement it into my code it just doesn't work. As you can see in my code it also uses a different format of showing the time. Can anyone show me the correct way to do it with an explanation? This is my code:

```
$(window).on('load', function () { "use strict";
    var labels      = ['weeks', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'],
        nextYear    = moment.tz("2017-05-03 17:00", "America/Los_Angeles"),
        template    = _.template($('#main-countdown-template').html()),
        currDate    = '00:00:00:00:00',
        nextDate    = '00:00:00:00:00',
        parser      = /([0-9]{2})/gi,
        $countdown  = $('#main-countdown');
    function strfobj(str) {
        var parsed = str.match(parser),
            obj = {};
        labels.forEach(function (label, i) {
            obj[label] = parsed[i];
        });
        return obj;
    }
    function diff(obj1, obj2) {
        var diff = [];
        labels.forEach(function (key) {
            if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
                diff.push(key);
            }
        });
        return diff;
    }
    var initData = strfobj(currDate);
    labels.forEach(function (label, i) {
        $countdown.append(template({
            curr: initData[label],
            next: initData[label],
            label: label
        }));
    });
    $countdown.countdown(nextYear.toDate(), function (event) {
        var newDate = event.strftime('%w:%d:%H:%M:%S'),
            data;
        if (newDate !== nextDate) {
            currDate = nextDate;
            nextDate = newDate;
            data = {
                'curr': strfobj(currDate),
                'next': strfobj(nextDate)
            };
            diff(data.curr, data.next).forEach(function (label) {
                var selector = '.%s'.replace(/%s/, label),
                    $node = $countdown.find(selector);
                $node.removeClass('flip');
                $node.find('.curr').text(data.curr[label]);
                $node.find('.next').text(data.next[label]);
                _.delay(function ($node) {
                    $node.addClass('flip');
                }, 50, $node);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `strftime` is not a standard JS method and will be causing an error unless it's part of a library you've included.

Comment: It's included with the jQuery countdown script, so that's not a problem!